# conditionally summarize several variables by group

Tags: r

I want to conditionally summarize several variables by group. The following code does that, but I'm not sure how to do this without specifying each variable and the conditions in the summarize step.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                  indicator = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
                  var1 = c(1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  var2 = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1))

# dat
#  group indicator var1 var2
#1     A         1    1    1
#2     A         2    0    0
#3     A         3    1    1
#4     B         1    2    1
#5     B         2    1    2
#6     B         3    2    1

dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(var1 = sum(var1[indicator==1 | indicator==2]),
            var2 = sum(var2[indicator==1 | indicator==2])) 

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  group  var1  var2
#* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     A     1     1
#2     B     3     3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('var'), ~sum(.[indicator %in% 1:2])))

#  group  var1  var2
#* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1     1
#2 B         3     3
```

Comment: thanks! clutch: `sum(.[indicator %in% 1:2])`